# Hide image in MS Office VBA

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

Used to write macros for Excel, it was easier, because the program showed the names of all the shapes / objects / pictures. Now I have a task in front of me: there is a picture or shapes in the document (MS Word), it is necessary to write a function or procedure that will hide / show my object. Thank you!

Comment: At least show what you have tried, or try something first :)

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution:

```
Dim objPic As Shape
For Each objPic In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    objPic.Delete
Next objPic
```

Comment: that does not hide the object, it deletes it.  something like `objPic.visible = false` would hide it